# crash due to coredata downgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm using Core Data in my app. The latest version of my app is v3.1.0, whose Core Data Model version is 4. And the old version v3.0.9, whose Core Data Model version is 3.
The case is when I downgrade my app from 3.1.0 to 3.0.9, it crashes.
If I set v3.1.0's current core data model version 3, downgrade my app to v3.0.9. It just works fine. So I think Core Data Model downgrade causes crash. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by simply deleting the existing store, if schema incompatibility errors occur during the initialization of persistentStoreCoordinator.
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
    }
This problem only happen on jailbreak devices, which can upgrade/downgrade apps freely. It helps me learn a little about the relationship between sqlite storage and core data model. Hope this helps:)